# Good auth plugin recommendation for grails 2.5.1?

Tags: authentication, grails

I am using Grails 2.5.1 and trying to use Authentication Plugin 2.0.1.

However, I have an error due to ConfigurationHolder not being found (this happens INSIDE authentication 2.0.1).

It seems that authentication 2.0.1 does not work with Grails 2.5.1 - it is not compatible with how grails structure changed in 2.4.x version.

What good authentication plugin version could I use? Or... How could I fix it? Or... what good authentication plugin alternative could I use?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that plugin is no longer under development. The [source code](https://github.com/Grailsrocks/grails-authentication) is on github, but no one has touched it in years. See [this](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2013/02/07/a-change-to-my-grails-plugins/).

## Alternatives

I don't know of a drop-in replacement. The closest one I know of is Grails Spring Security.

## Fixing it

With some keyboard grease you can upgrade the plugin. If the holder error is the one I'm thinking of, it's easy to fix. Here's a general guideline:

1. With the source code in hand, check which version of Grails the p!ugin was written in.
2. Upgrade the plugin to the next minor version. Avoid skipping around.
3. Using the *upgrading from grails* section of the Grails documentation make the necessary changes.
4. Test, then rinse and repeat.
5. Change the plugin version and do a [plugin local install](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins).
6. Change the version of the plugin in your app so that it uses the new version.
7. Consider publishing your changes on github.